# ssh get old public key from backed up private key

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, public-key

I backed up and encrypted my private key but nothing else.

I am trying to get my public key out of it but don't know how. I am trying `ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` but it says permissions are too open on id_rsa so the key will be ignored.

Did I screw up or is it possible to get my public key back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If openssh refuses to read the file, you could use openssl

```
openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa -pubout -out ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Nevertheless, you won't be able to use any of them until you correct your permissions.

`~` must be 775 at most, `~/.ssh` 700, `~/.ssh/id_rsa` 600